# Calculate integral inside ball $\int_{r<a}^{ }\frac{d^{3}r}{\left|R-r\right|^{2}}$

Tags: integration

There is a ball of radius $a$ and a point $R$ inside this ball $(|R| <a)$ . Calculate the integral.

$$T\left(R\right)=\int_{r<a}^{ }\frac{d^{3}r}{\left|R-r\right|^{2}}$$

I tried to switch to spherical coordinates, but I don't understand what to do with the length of the vector in the denominator, what can you advise?

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, assume $R$ is on the $z$ axis. Then, in spherical coordinates, the integral becomes

$$I=\int_{r\lt a}\frac{ 1}{|R-r|^2}dr^3
= 2\pi \int_0^a\int_0^\pi
\frac{r^2\sin\theta}{ R^2-2Rr\cos \theta +r^2}dr d\theta
$$
Integrate over $\theta $ and then $r$ to obtain

\begin{align}
I = \frac{2\pi}R\int_0^a
r[\ln(r+R)-\ln|r-R|)]dr
= \pi \left(\frac{a^2-R^2}R\ln\frac{a+R}{a-R}+2a\right)
\end{align}